# why is it showing the 6 as the length of the array instead of 5?

Tags: c, arrays

I'v made a c program in which I'm calculating the length of an array.

But when i enter a string it shows 1 extra character like when i enter `"Jason"` which is of 5 character long it shows 6 characters.

Further, i have made a loop that loops through every element and there also I see 6 values in which the 6th one seems to be the garbage value.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
    char a[5];
    int i;
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    gets(a);
    for (i=0; a[i]!='\0'; i++){
        printf(Ch no %d is %c \n",i,a[i]);
    }
    printf("Lentgh of array = %d",i);
    getch();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do not post code as image links. Edit your question and add code in text format.

Comment: If this is a C program, why did you tag this C++?

Answer (score 2):

[gets()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/) adds a null character after the characters in your input string. If you type "Jason", which is 5 chars long, you should make your array of size "6", providing room for null-character appended by the function (see link).

Your code, as it is, is exhibiting undefined behaviour when you type "Jason" (as you are overflowing your `a` array).

---

Also, as a good practice, avoid using C-style arrays in new C++ code. Prefer `std::vector`, or in this particular case `std::string`. Those will take care of memory management for you, avoiding potential overflows as in you example.

If you are compiling this code as C++ code, you should include your C headers using the form:

```
#include <cstdio>
```

And finally, `gets` was deprecated since C++11 standard. If you write C++ code, you should consider more recent (and safer) alternative. (thanks @Matthew Gunn for his comment).

Comment: If he changes his code to `char a[255];` it will work.

Comment: Also, one should *not* use gets as it has no bounds checking!

Comment: Yes, as long as he types an input string that is strictly less than 255 chars long ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't initialise the array with empty data the last element is garbage as your string isn't long enough to set the last element.

Also remember that arrays are zero based and don't confuse the length of your array with the length of the string which is null terminated.  For example:

```
char someString[10] = "jason";

sizeof(someString) // will be 10
strlen(someString) // will be 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings in C all are terminated by a null byte (`\0`). Your call of the `gets()` function adds this to your string automatically, and so the string `"Jason"` is actually an array of characters that looks like this:

```
{'J','a','s','o','n','\n','\0'}
```

You see, in actuality that is 7 characters. `strlen()` by design doesn't count the `\0`, but its there.

Comment: `gets()` does not save the `'\n'`.